# How to detect which finger is scanned on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, fingerprint, touch-id

When user scanned his finger, i want to learn which finger is printed, middle or second or nth.

Is it possible on IOS/CORDOVA or do you have an hack for it?

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible for a user to label their finger scans that is optional and un-reliable. Other than that I don't believe the software can detect which finger; even pet paws have even registered.

Further iOS does not keep the scanned finger print but that information may not help you.

Comment: How can i do with label? i couldn understand the possibla way

Answer (score 0):

Yes an no.

It is not possible to do this with the standard APIs. It is possible to do this with a jailbroken iOS device. (I just don't know how but I've seen demo videos of apps that use the fingerprint name to identify which finger was used.)

Please file a radar bug/feature request on this. It is a completely reasonable request. The more of us that do it, the greater the chance that Apple will give us the API we need.